# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, gcc

I was given a program to install and after running the makefile, I got the error

```
gcc -o SD_Plot SD_Plot.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl
```

I already installed the GNU Scientific Library, and made sure it was installed by checking with the package manager, but I am still getting this error. Since I was given the program, I am sure the makefile is correct, so there must be something wrong on my machine. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the dev package.

In my case is `libgsl0-dev`